# azure functions visual studio 2017 15.3 error

Tags: visual-studio, azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-functions

I just installed latest Preview of Visual Studio 2017 15.3 (Preview 4) and Azure Functions Tools form Marketplace.
When I try to create a new Functions project I get the following error: "No template could be found with the group identity 'Microsoft.Azure Functions.ProjectTemplates'".

It's a fresh installation, I only installed Functions Tools, nothing more.

My OS: Windows 7 x64

Answer (score 0, accepted):

work around.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
      <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net461</TargetFramework>
      </PropertyGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
      </ItemGroup>
      <ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
      </ItemGroup>
    </Project>
```

1. create function .csproj file manually using above content
2. save this file as myfunction.csproj.
3. right click solution and choose add existing project and choose
   project created in step 2
4. now u can start working on this by adding references and function
   code.

Comment: other solution is during installation manually check the component install .net 4.7 framework it will be under asp.net or cloud anyone of them. i got lightning yellow sign and it works fine now